# Does "vertical" distance require saying Tefillat Haderech?

Tags: blessing, tefilat-haderech

Does "vertical" travel require saying Tefillat haderech? Examples:

- Bungee jumping
- Hang gliding
- Ski lift / cable car
- Mountain climbing / rapelling (using rope to scale the mountain.)
- Sky Diving / parachuting
- "Blue Devil" (air show / air force) demo

In all these cases, let's assume that the vertical distance is about 12,000 feet - close to 2 miles. (I don't know if there is a minimum horizontal distance requirement for this bracha, so I'm assuming an equivalent requirement for verticals.)

Comment: http://www.space.com/17961-supersonic-skydive-worlds-highest-space-jump.html

Comment: @YEZ - Can't access that site (blocked). Can you excerpt the main ideas?

Comment: Sounds more like the mishna in Berachot 4:4
 רבי יהושע אומר המהלך **במקום סכנה** מתפלל תפלה קצרה אומר: הושע השם את עמךz את שארית ישראל בכל פרשת העבור יהיו צרכיהם לפניך בא"י שומע תפלה"

Comment: @DanF the space.com reference says in part "World's Highest Skydive! Daredevil Makes Record-Breaking Supersonic Jump
by Mike Wall, SPACE.com Senior Writer   |   October 14, 2012 02:00pm ET

Felix Baumgartner makes the highest skydive ever Oct. 14, 2012.
Skydiver Felix Baumgartner makes the highest skydive ever Oct. 14, 2012. He jumped from 128,000 feet (39,000 meters), or about 24 miles up, during the Red Bull Stratos mission."

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok - Interesting point and I may raise the "danger" issue as a separate question. If you "volunteer" for the dangers such as in bungee jumping, should you still make any bracha? After all you are not allowed to intentionally place yourself in "danger". Also, thanks for article text. Have to edit to include skydiving.

Comment: What about being launched in a rocket? [According to Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=how+far+away+is+the+moon&oq=how+far+away+is+the+moon&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.4556j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8&gws_rd=ssl), the distance between here and the Moon is 238,900 miles, which should be enough for tefillas haderech.

Comment: @Shokhet - you probably WOULD have to say Tefillat Haderech on your trip to the moon. Perhaps the Israeli (can't recall his name) who was on the space ship that exploded on re-entry did say Tefillat Haderech, but, alas, we will never know.

Comment: @DanF Ilan Ramon. Went looking for the sefer they published before he left with all the halacha questions he asked, couldn't find it easily enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kitzur says in סימן סח - דין תפלת הדרך ושאר דברים שצריכין לזהר בדרך ובו י"ב סעיפים:

> סעיף ב': אֵין לְהִתְפַּלֵּל אוֹתָהּ אֶלָּא אִם כֵּן יֵשׁ לוֹ לָלֶכֶת לְכָל הַפָּחוֹת פַּרְסָה.‏

As I elaborated [here](http://halocho.blogspot.co.il/2010/01/halocho-487-how-far-must-one-travel-to.html):

`One does not say Tefilat HaDerech unless the trip is one Parsa (~4 Km / ~2.5 miles) long - outside the city.`

There's a dispute amongst Posking if we're talking about actual distance, or the time it took to walk that distance. For example, the Kitzur-S.A.-Yalkut-Yosef (110:2) says that one only says it with Shem-uMalchut if one has to travel at least 72 minutes during that day.

> ואמנם אינו חותם בשם ומלכות רק כשנוסע מעיר לעיר, ויש בנסיעתו כשיעור פרסה, שהוא שעה וחומש, [שבעים ושתים דקות], בין ברכבת ובין באוטובוס וברכב פרטי. ואף אם יש בדרך נקודות ישוב ומושבים, גם בזה מנהגינו לברך תפלת הדרך בשם ומלכות, אם נוסע בכביש בינעירוני במשך שעה וחומש. אבל אם נוסע מעיר לעיר פחות משיעור זה, לא יברך בשם ומלכות. ואם יש בהליכה וחזרה בו ביום שיעור פרסה, מברך בשם ומלכות, אף נסע מחצית שיעור פרסה בבוקר, ומחציתה בלילה. אבל אם נסע בלילה כחצי שעה, ולן בעיר אחרת, ולמחרת נסע עוד כשיעור שעה, אין הנסיעות מצטרפות, ויאמר תפלת הדרך בלא שם ומלכות. [ילקוט יוסף מהדורת תשס''ד, תפלה כרך ב, סימן קי הערה ב]. ‏

Either way, I don't believe it's an issue for your vertical activities.

For Hang Gliding you surely have the same halachot as an airplane - and if you glide more than 4 Km / for longer than 72 minutes outside the city - or over a body of water - then my guess would be that you have to say Tefilat HaDerech.

That said, the Aruch HaShulachan (as well as the B'er Heitev) in סימן קי - דיני תפילת ''הביננו'', ותפילת הדרך והפועלים says:

> טו: אין לאמר תפילת הדרך אלא אם כן יש לו לילך פרסה, דפחות מפרסה לא נקרא ''דרך''. **אלא אם כן הוא מקום סכנה, דאז גם בפחות מזה יש לאומרה**.‏

"If one is in a dangerous area, then one says it even for less than a Parsa."

Note that he says *dangerous place* and not *dangerous activity*.

Comment: Just a note: it is still possible that hanging from a piece of fabric over a body of water might be classed as a *makom sakana* [not that I wouldn't do it necessarily, but I don't understand your distinction between "dangerous place" and "dangerous activity"]